# Dock (functionally) similar to Unity or Windows 7

Tags: xfce, dock

I've been running Gnome (v1 and v2) and use xfce now. But ever since I gave Unity a try when Ubuntu shipped it as default a couple years ago (and have been using Win7 for some games), I've been looking for a dock with simple mechanisms that both "systems" (Unity/Win7) provide:

- Windows key to open a menu where I can start to type to start programs directly. (The dock doesn't need to do that, xfce-whisker-menu does this job fine already.)
- Pin apps to the dock so they stay at the same position in the dock, whether started or not. (This is common, awn and cairo dock for example do that.)
- Start or switch to the app at n-th position via Winkey+n. (This seems to be the feature thats hard to come by.)

I know I'm essentially describing Unity and in theory should give it another try, but I don't want to change my xfce setup I have. Does anybody know a nice way to add that to xfce/xfwm?

[Asked on askUbuntu already](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667199/dock-functionally-similar-to-unity-or-windows-7), but there wasn't any answer yet.

Comment: Please avoid cross-posting, this practice is discouraged on the Stack Exchange network :) I have flagged your question on AskUbuntu since I believe it is more suited to U&L.

Comment: Sure, will do. Never occurred to me, since so many questions are in a ghastly state, but I'll try to chose the most fitting site next time.

Comment: @JakobLenfers If you poste a question on one site and then found it may suitable for another site, then you can request to migrate that to another site question by flagging in order to moderator attention instead of cross-posting on multiple site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [DockbarX](https://launchpad.net/dockbar) that does what I want it to do. It isn't perfect from my point of view, but I'll talk to the devs about that, maybe they can enhance those parts. It even integrates into xfce-panel, for those who might need it.